# CRONTAB executing Python who executes Node with puppeteer for web scraping not working

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-scraping, cron, puppeteer

I made this web scraper to get tables in web pages. I used puppeteer (not knowing that has issues with crontab), Python for the cleaning and to handle the output to a DB

But for my surprise when I execute it like

```
*/50 * * * * cd path /python3 /script.py >> cron.log 2>&1
```

it executes but the log file is empty and no info in database.

I made an example on Github:

https://github.com/GST5555/web_scrapper_get_tables

I don't want to make a shell to execute it.

Comment: How do you know that it executes? The `cd path` is a separate command from `/python3 /script.py` so I would not expect the script to be executed.

Comment: I see, other answers suggest to put the cd path before the execution commands, anyways I tried it in many ways and it still not working with crontab

Comment: what the previous user meant was you're running two separate commands, so you either need to use `&&` or `;` between them. instead of `cd`ing just use the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it was npm fault, learned to use yarn, learned that node and npm sucks... and I was on AWS and so the installations weren't being made properly, the solution was to update node and install all with yarn...